# Parsing json webservice Response with Gson (Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY)

Tags: java, android, json, web-services, gson

I'm trying to parse the spotify web-service response to get an artists' tracks which is like this:

```
{
"info": {
    "num_results": 2974,
    "limit": 100,
    "offset": 0,
    "query": "foo",
    "type": "track",
    "page": 1
},
"tracks": [
    {
        "album": {
            "released": "2009",
            "href": "spotify:album:1zCNrbPpz5OLSr6mSpPdKm",
            "name": "Greatest Hits",
            "availability": {
                "territories": "AD AR AT AU BE BG BO BR CA CH CL CO CR CY CZ DE DK DO EC EE ES FI FR GB GR GT HK HN HU IE IS IT LI LT LU LV MC MT MX MY NI NL NO NZ PA PE PH PL PT PY RO SE SG SI SK SV TR TW US UY"
            }
        },
        "name": "Everlong",
        "popularity": "0.79",
        "external-ids": [
            {
                "type": "isrc",
                "id": "USRW29600011"
            }
        ],
        "length": 249.986,
        "href": "spotify:track:07q6QTQXyPRCf7GbLakRPr",
        "artists": [
            {
                "href": "spotify:artist:7jy3rLJdDQY21OgRLCZ9sD",
                "name": "Foo Fighters"
            }
        ],
        "track-number": "3"
    }]
}
```

I am using the Gson library to do this. So far I have tried this in my java code:

```
JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
JsonObject jObject = parser.parse(jsonString).getAsJsonObject();
JsonArray jArray = jObject.get("tracks") .getAsJsonArray();


Gson gson = new Gson();
List<Track> trackArr = new ArrayList<Track>();

Type collectiontype = new TypeToken<Collection<Track>>(){}.getType();
Collection<Track> trackColl = gson.fromJson(jArray.toString(), collectiontype);
```

But I am getting the error : com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY

I don't understand why is it expecting begin object if I am doing "getAsJsonArray()" when trying to get the "tracks" object whihc in the json string is an array [].

The list of 'Track' was when I was doing this in a loop to get all the tracks into an array:

```
for (JsonElement jsonElement : jArray) {
  Type collectiontype = new TypeToken<Collection<Track>>(){}.getType();
  Collection<Track> trackCol = gson.fromJson(jsonElement, collectiontype);
  trackArr.add((Track) trackCol);

}
```

What am I doind wrong here ? 
I appreciate any guidance.

Answer (score 0):

You don`t have to use extra library to parse a JSON file. Also use this [link](http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/) to read your JSON file in a human readable way.

Use the Native one as the following example:

Imports:

```
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;
```

The code of parsing will be:

```
JSONObject fileJSONObject = new JSONObject(response);

JSONObject infoJSONObject = fileJSONObject.getJSONObject("info");
JSONArray tracksJSONArray = fileJSONObject.getJSONArray("tracks");

//Parsing the info
String trackType = infoJSONObject.getString("type");
String trackLimit = infoJSONObject.getString("limit");
//The rest of attributes


//Parsing the track list
JSONObject object;
for(int i=0;i<tracksJSONArray.length();i++){
    object = tracksJSONArray.getJSONObject(i);
    String trackName = object.getString("name");
    //The rest of attributes

}
```

I recommend for you to Create a track `class` that contain all the needed attributes and their `setter` and `getter` and at the end of the parsing of each track create a new track.

I hope it helps

Answer (score -4):

You can use my lib for solve this problem. For example you can do it.

```
private static List<Object> SpotifyTest()
{
    InformationHandler informationHandler   = null;
    Injector injector                       = Guice.createInjector(new Module());
    informationHandler                      = injector.getInstance(SpotifyService.class);
    informationHandler.executeWithValue("la bamba");
    return informationHandler.getDataModel();
}
```

The solution returns a List with a lot of HashMap where each key is a enumeration of key on service, the enumarator is:

```
public enum SpotifyKey
{
    ALBUM_RELEASED,
    ALBUM_HREF,
    ALBUM_NAME,
    ALBUM_AVAILABILITY,
    NAME,
    POPULARITY,
    LENGTH,
    HREF,
    ARTIST_HREF,
    ARTIST_NAME,
    TRACK_NUMBER,
    ID
}
```

Also you can view the code on github https://github.com/WeCodeMx/WCMPopularService/tree/develop